# With two overlapping sudo rules, more restrictive rule is used?

Tags: sudo

I have the following two rules in separate files in `sudoers.d`. The user `foobar` is in the `sudo` group. The expectation is that the user `foobar` can login only via `ssh` with public key auth because their password is scrambled to a random value when their user is created. They should then set their password by running `sudo passwd foobar` after accessing the machine via `ssh`.

```
# /etc/sudoers.d/sudo-group
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) ALL

# /etc/sudoers.d/change-own-passwd
foobar  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/passwd foobar
```

However, the user is still prompted for their password:

```
$ which passwd
/usr/bin/passwd

$ sudo -ll
User foobar may run the following commands on bizbazz:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: root
    Options: !authenticate
    Commands:
    /usr/bin/passwd foobar

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    Commands:
    ALL

$ sudo passwd foobar
[sudo] password for foobar: ^C
sudo: a password is required
```

Comment: Why would `sudo` continue searching after it matched the `%sudo` rule? Also, `passwd` with no parameter changes `$USER`s passwd. `/bin/passwd` is setuid `root` for this purpose. Read `man passwd`.

Comment: @waltinator  `passwd` will only change a user's password *if they know the existing password*. If their account is locked or if their password is scrambled (i.e., a new user account) then they cannot use `passwd` to change their own password, even if they have access via `ssh`.

Comment: That being said, order does seem to matter with the sudo rules. Moving the files to `000-sudo-group` and `100-change-own-passwd` ensures that the last matching rule is the desired one. There are a couple of strategies I could see the authors of sudo selecting (first, last, most specific) and I don't see any clear reason to pick 'last' over any other strategy.

Answer (score 4):

> SUDOERS FILE FORMAT
>
> ...
>
> When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  Where there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is
> not necessarily the most specific match).

From `man 5 sudoers`

So order matters when applying the rules. Changing the names to be lexicographically ordered (`000-sudo-group` and `100-change-own-passwd`) worked around the issue.